# Error using standalone.sty - memory exceeded

Tags: texstudio, standalone, memory

I have the following in my preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt,PhD,wordcount,twoside,anon]{muthesis}
    \usepackage{graphicx,stackengine}
    \usepackage{url} 
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, afterpage,float, cancel}
    \usepackage{xcolor, graphicx,enumerate}
    \usepackage{bm} 
    \usepackage{siunitx}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{mathtools} %right cases (rcases)
    \usepackage[para]{threeparttable} % for footnotes inside table
    \usepackage{chemformula}
    \usepackage{gensymb} %for \degree symbol
    \usepackage{comment}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{booktabs} %\toprule, \bottomrule, \midrule
    \usepackage{mdframed}
    \usepackage[labelfont =bf,font=small,justification=justified]{caption}
    \usepackage[labelfont =bf,font=small,justification=centering]{subcaption} 
    \usepackage[subpreambles = true]{standalone} %standalone tikzpicture
    \usepackage{pgfplots} 
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.3}
    \usepackage[
    backend=bibtex,
    style=authoryear-ibid,
    citestyle=authoryear,
    natbib=true,
    sorting=nyvt,
    firstinits=true,
    uniquename=init,  % this option is compatible with firstinits
    maxcitenames=2,
    maxbibnames=99
    citetracker=true,
    doi=false,isbn=false,url=false
    ]{biblatex}
    \usepackage[hidelinks,hypertexnames=false]{hyperref}
```

It gives me the following error. Also says that the tex memory is exceeded - fatal error.

```
\let\sa@orig@document\document
Underfull \vbox (badness 10000) has occurred while \output is active []
```

I have included an overleaf link below which contains the muthesis.cls.
https://www.overleaf.com/read/nvgvqpckxyfm

Comment: The code you posted is not compilable. Please post the *complete* code from `\documentclass` all the way to the `\end{document}` that when compiled throws the error you say. Other than that, you are missing a `,` after `maxbibnames=99`.

Comment: the fragment you show is just a warning about a poor page break not an error and the log at the overleaf link shows many errors but no out of memory error, and the code fragment you have posted can not be run as it is incomplete. This makes it impossible to guess what can be the issue.

Comment: Ok, thanks. As the file is large, I have to figure it out. Thanks for your input.

Comment: If you are using the `subpreambles` option of the `standalone` package make sure the input files are proper formatted. Check the `standalone` manual for more details. The `\begin{document}` in the sub-files must be on a line of its own for example.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I think I found the source of the problem. It was because I was using matlab2tikz  to generate tikz images/figures, which exceeded the allowable memory. I had to input .eps versions of the figures which removed the errors.